# $SU(2)$ symmetry of $\mathcal{L}=\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}\Phi - \Phi^{\dagger}M\Phi$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, group-theory

I'm considering a Lagrangian of two complex scalar field:
$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_{\mu}\phi_1^{*}\partial^{\mu}\phi_1-m_1^2\phi_1^{*}\phi_1+\partial_{\mu}\phi_2^{*}\partial^{\mu}\phi_2-m_2^2\phi_2^{*}\phi_2$$
It can be written in a doublet:

$$\Phi_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
      \phi_1\\
      \phi_2
    \end{pmatrix}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
\Phi_1^{\dagger} = \begin{pmatrix}
      \phi_1^\dagger &
      \phi_2^\dagger
    \end{pmatrix}
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
M = \begin{pmatrix}
      m_1 & 0 \\
      0 & m_2 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}\Phi - \Phi^{\dagger}M\Phi$$
It has an internal global symmetry $SU(2)$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\Phi^{'}= e^{\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma} \Phi\\
\Phi^{'\dagger} = \Phi^{\dagger}e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma} \end{cases} $$
I'd like to check it explicitly but I'm stuck:
$$\mathcal{L^{'}}=\partial_{\mu}\Phi^{\dagger}\partial^{\mu}\Phi - \Phi^{\dagger}M\Phi$$

$$\mathcal{L^{'}}=\begin{pmatrix}
      \partial_{\mu}\phi_1^{*} &
      \partial_{\mu}\phi_2^{*}
    \end{pmatrix} e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma}
    e^{+\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma}
 \begin{pmatrix}
      \partial^{\mu}\phi_1 \\
      \partial^{\mu}\phi_2 
    \end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
      \phi_1^{*} &
      \phi_2^{*}
    \end{pmatrix}
e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma}
 \begin{pmatrix}
      m_1 & 0 \\
      0 & m_2 
    \end{pmatrix} 
e^{+\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma}
\begin{pmatrix}
      \phi_1\\
      \phi_2
    \end{pmatrix}$$
However:
$$ S_1=e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma}
 \begin{pmatrix}
      m_1 & 0 \\
      0 & m_2 
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
      m_1e^{-\frac{i\alpha_3}{2}} & m_2e^{-\frac{i(\alpha_1-i\alpha_2)}{2}} \\
      m_1 e^{-\frac{i(\alpha_1+i\alpha_2)}{2}}& m_2e^{\frac{i\alpha_3}{2}} 
    \end{pmatrix}$$
$$
 S_2=\begin{pmatrix}
      m_1 & 0 \\
      0 & m_2 
    \end{pmatrix}  e^{-\frac{i}{2}\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\sigma} =\begin{pmatrix}
      m_1e^{-\frac{i\alpha_3}{2}} & m_1 e^{-\frac{i(\alpha_1-i\alpha_2)}{2}} \\
      m_2 e^{-\frac{i(\alpha_1+i\alpha_2)}{2}} & m_2e^{\frac{i\alpha_3}{2}} 
    \end{pmatrix}$$
So $S_2=S_1^{T}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the fact $m_1 \neq m_2$ break the $SU(2)$ symmetry?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure that you're not exponentiating your matrices correctly;  it looks like you've found the exponential of $-\frac{i}{2} \vec{\alpha} \cdot \vec{\sigma}$ by taking the exponential of each entry.  But this is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\text{SU}(2)$ symmetry of this theory is only preserved when $m_1=m_2\equiv m$, in which case $M=m\textbf{1}$. Otherwise, the internal $\text{SU}(2)$ symmetry is broken down to $\text{U}(1)\times\text{U}(1)$, one for each scalar field. Something similar to this happens in QCD, in which the up and down quarks have nearly the same mass, and the approximate $\text{SU}(2)$ *isospin* symmetry is useful for classifying low-mass mesons and baryons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but then the doublet still has some global internal symmetry a part from U(1) for each field?

Comment: @StefanoBarone Of course, there are two commuting U(1)s, one  for each scalar field. You could make life easier for you if you eschewed complex notation and wrote down the 4 real degrees of freedom; then, ask yourself: How does the mass matrix break the original SO(4)  symmetry explicitly? Take $m_1=0$ for simplicity.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for your reply, do you know some references where these calculations about symmetries for multiplet for both complex fields and fermions are performed in pedantic detail?

Comment: @StefanoBarone I added a clarification on the $\text{U}(1)$ in the answer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the symmetry of the original Lagrangian is $U(2) = U(1) \times SU(2)$, which is then broken to $U(1) \times U(1)$ when $m_1 \neq n_2$. In other words, one of the $U(1)$ factors that remains after the symmetry is broken was "outside" of the original $SU(2)$ subgroup that the OP was concerned with.

Comment: @StefanoBarone The thesis paper of Longhitano referenced in my [geeky footnote](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292899/creating-a-qm-state-of-definite-position-in-fock-space) on the custodial group question should cover it, but any remedial group theory review in a serviceable QFT course should do. Do you want me to do the explicit SO(4) ~ SU(2) x SU(2) breaking with 4 scalars here ?

Answer (score 4):

Ignore all normalizations, since this is an issue of symmetry, and consider real numbers $a,b,c,d$, s.t.
$$
\phi_1=a+ib, \qquad  \phi_2=c+id ,
$$
and define $m_1=m_2 + \Delta$.

Then, for the real 4-vector $\vec \varphi\equiv (a,b,c,d)^T$, you have
$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_{\mu} \vec \varphi \cdot \partial^{\mu} \vec \varphi -m_2  \vec \varphi \cdot  \vec \varphi
-\Delta (a^2+b^2).
$$
It is manifest that, for $\Delta=0$, this expression is *SO(4) ~ SU(2)×SU(2)* invariant. (One of these two *SU(2)* s is the *SU(2)* you display, but the other one is less easy to see in your language, and corresponds to the "right custodial" *SU(2)* of the SM, a global approximate symmetry of it. Through *SO(4)*, you can appreciate there are 6 transformations mixing your 4 real scalars.)

But the introduction of the explicit perturbation   $\Delta$ breaks this *SO(4)* into $U(1)\times U(1) \sim O(2) \times O(2)$, the two *O(2)* s rotating the doublets *(a,b)* and *(c,d)*, independently, respectively.  The other 4 generators of *SO(4)* are *explicitly* broken, since you cannot preserve the last, perturbation term, any other way--try it.