# Eigenstates of X operator in harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I want to find eigenstates of $\hat{x} = a + a^\dagger$  operator, I've started by considering a linear combination like $\sum_{m=0} c_m (a^\dagger)^m |0 \rangle$ and match $c_m$ such that linear combination to be an eigenstate of $\hat{x}$.

But it leads to a recursive relation on $c_m$ which seems hard to evaluate, and I happen to know that eigenstates should be labeled by a complex number $z$, so I don't know how to enter it in my analysis.

Could anyone help me or mention a reference?

Comment: There's no reason to label eigenstates by a complex number... $\hat{x}$ is Hermitian so its eigenvalues are real.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/292899/creating-a-qm-state-of-definite-position-in-fock-space).  i.e. $\frac{e^{x^2/2}}{\pi^{1/4}} e^{-(a^\dagger-\sqrt{2} x)^2/2} |0\rangle$.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos: Is this related to the inverse Weierstrass transfoms $
\exp\left\{+\tau\frac {d^2}{dx^2}\right\} H_n(x/\sqrt{4\tau}) = \frac 1{\sqrt {4 \pi\tau }} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_n(y/\sqrt{4\tau}) e^{-(x-y)^2/4\tau} dy = \tau^{-n/2}x^n?
$

Comment: @mike stone. I'm sure it is... I believe it's all in the Cnudde & DeBie paper cited in my answer, but I did not bother with the fine details of the Segal-Bargmann transform of the esthetes... I just utilized the seat-of-the-pants shortcut $
\langle  n|  x \rangle= \frac{1}{\pi^{1/4}\sqrt{2^n~n!}}~ (x-\partial_x)^n~ e^{-x^2/2}  $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normalized eigenstates of the frequency $\Omega$ Harmonic oscillator are
$$
\langle x|n\rangle=\frac{\varphi_n(\sqrt{\Omega_0} x)}{(\Omega_0)^{1/4}}
$$
where
$$
\varphi_n(x)\equiv  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}} H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}.
$$
We want to expand the $\hat x$ eigenvalue $x_0$ eigenstate wavefunction $\langle x|x_0\rangle=\delta(x-x_0)$ in terms of these, but the completeness relation tells us that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \langle x|n\rangle\langle n|x_0\rangle=\delta(x-x_0)
$$
and so
$$
| x_0\rangle= \sum_n|n\rangle\langle n|x_0\rangle=\sum_n |n\rangle \frac{\varphi_n(\sqrt{\Omega_0} x_0)}{(\Omega_0)^{1/4}}
$$

I don't know where complex numbers are coming in. Are you sure that you do not want to introduce  coherent states
$$
|z\rangle =e^{a^\dagger z}|0\rangle?
$$
We do have
$$
 z\in {\mathbb C},
$$
but these are not eigenstates of $\hat x$, but rather of $\hat a$.